# writeValueToProperty isn't available

Tags: knockout.js

I'm doing a custom binding, my first version required the databound property to be a observable, but I just released that users of the binding probably could want to use a standard property (If they are not interested in being notified when the value has changed).

To support this I looked at how the value binding is implemented, and it uses

```
ko.jsonExpressionRewriting.writeValueToProperty
```

to write values both to observables or standard properties.

This is an internal ko namespace so i cant use it from my binding, how am I supposed to call this method?

**edit:** 
I have a pull request at github to fix this
https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/806

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knockout places a function in the resulting object from the `allBindingsAccessor` that you can use to write to a non-observable model value.

If your binding was called `myBinding`, then your code might look like:

```
        if (ko.isObservable(modelValue)) {
            modelValue(valueToWrite);
        }                
        else { //non-observable
           allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers.myBinding(valueToWrite);   
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, this is exactly what the writeValueToProperty function does, would be nice if you could access it through the ko.utils namespace or whatever so we dont need to duplicate code

Comment: `writeValueToProperty` was just factored out in 2.1.  Prior to that, we were doing this "by hand" using code similar to what I added above (with some additional checks to see if the objects are defined).  Maybe we should consider making it a public API.

Comment: Yeah I think you should really consider that, never nice to have to duplicate code... Anyway, I copied your methoid for now to my own API, works nice. I've made a own selected binding for the options binding, it doesnt use the object reference as the built in value binding. Tou guys should consider adding something similar ;) http://jsfiddle.net/u4ZuJ/

Comment: In the past, for this scenario, I usually match it up in the view model / data loading code, but I have also done it with an additional binding that you just tack on before options/value like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rzncK/

Comment: @Anders that last one is fine, except that you end up doing more work than necessary. We really only need to match up the initial object to a corresponding object in the array the very first time.  After that the value binding takes care of it.  In your case, the value binding takes care of it, it goes through your write, then your read is triggered and it does more looping to re-verify it.  So, I think that it is preferable to just match up the objects initially and then let  the option/value bindings do their thing.

Comment: True, but its not a big loss, plus your method mutates the state from the start, mine only changes what is returned on read, its first when you write that it mutates state, also your example wont work if you update the model after init, but that is off course easy fixed. Anyway, thanks, If you want me to I can open a issue on github so you guys dont forget to make it public ;)

Comment: I know this it is not a big deal, but I wouldn't see why you wouldn't want to mutate the state right away. You basically want the selected object to be a reference to an item in the array rather than two objects that just look the same.   If you have lots of items in your array of choices, then you will be doing extra work everytime to match it up even though it is already correct after the first time.

Comment: A select list isnt ideal with that many items, a autocomplete box of some sort works better for those scenarios.