# KnockoutJs v3 - _ko_property_writers = undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to get my custom binding to work with both observables and plain objects. I followed the answer in this question:

[writeValueToProperty isn't available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218799/writevaluetoproperty-isnt-available)

However, if I look at the object returned if I execute the allBindingsAccessor, the property '_ko_property_writers' is undefined.

Does anyone know if this has changed at all in version 3 of knockout?

edit

Sorry I should have stated, I am trying to 'write' the value back to the model, in an observable agnostic way

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. There is no way you can write to a non-observable value from a custom binding (unless that value is an object and you want to write to one of its properties). If calling `valueAccessor` delivers a plain value - like, a number - then you get a *copy* of that number. You have no way of changing it in its original location. How would you write to that?

Comment: Well, it seems it was possible, I'm just asking whether or not the undocumented function noted in the linked question has been removed in v3. I've got it to work now using a dirty dirty hack - if no one posts an answer I'll post it but I won't be proud.

Comment: Well. Whatever you did, it won't be very clean, just as you said. I'd argue that it goes against the design principles of Knockout, maybe changing your approach is more useful than writing a dirty hack? What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: Its for a colleague, he's just using raw objects for a display grid - I have told him he should be using a custom class for each row but hey. Plus the default bindings KO has, e.g. 'value' work fine for raw properties so I thought I'd try to get my custom binding working in a similar way.

Comment: If you just pass the raw object through the mapping plugin you should be done. That's way more reasonable than using custom hacks to get functionality that essentially already is available for free. IMO.

Answer (score 2):

This was helpful for me:

```
ko.expressionRewriting.twoWayBindings.numericValue = true;  
ko.bindingHandlers.numericValue = {  
...  
}
```

It is defined after specifying binding as two-way.
So I can use something like that inside my custom binding:

```
ko.expressionRewriting.writeValueToProperty(underlying, allBindingsAccessor, 'numericValue', parseFloat(value));
```

writeValueToProperty is defined internally as:

```
writeValueToProperty: function(property, allBindings, key, value, checkIfDifferent) {
    if (!property || !ko.isObservable(property)) {
        var propWriters = allBindings.get('_ko_property_writers');
            if (propWriters && propWriters[key])
            propWriters[key](value);
    } else if (ko.isWriteableObservable(property) && (!checkIfDifferent || property.peek() !== value)) {
        property(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is with `ko.unwrap` as described here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

For example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        // First get the latest data that we're bound to
        var value = valueAccessor();

        // Next, whether or not the supplied model property is observable, get its current value
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);

        // Grab some more data from another binding property
        var duration = allBindings.get('slideDuration') || 400; // 400ms is default duration unless otherwise specified

        // Now manipulate the DOM element
        if (valueUnwrapped == true)
            $(element).slideDown(duration); // Make the element visible
        else
            $(element).slideUp(duration);   // Make the element invisible
    }
};
```

In that example `valueUnwrapped` is correct whether the user bound to an observable or a normal object.

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have stated, I am trying to 'write' the value back to the model, in an observable agnostic way.